# How can I rerender my vue template after changing v-for list?

Tags: vue.js

So I'm trying to change a list based on a whether the elements are considered active or not. I do this through a computed data array. Basically a Search Function. However my template does not rerender and update automatically, even though I try to force it with this.forceUpdate().

This is my v-for in template:

```
<ion-list>
        <div v-for="project in activeProjects" :key="project">
          <ion-item v-if="checkemail!=project.creator">
            <ion-button @click="openProjectPage(project.id)">{{ project.name }}</ion-button>
          </ion-item>
      </div>
</ion-list>
```

This is my computed array. The Log returns the correct things.

```
computed: {
    activeProjects: function() {
      return this.myprojects.filter(function(u){
        console.log(u);
        return u.active
      })
    }
  }
```

And this is where I update the activity. The Log also returns the correct things.

```
search: function(){
    for(var i=0; i<this.myprojects.length; i++){
      if(this.myprojects[i].name.includes(this.searchinput)){
        this.myprojects[i].active=true;
        console.log(this.myprojects[i])
      }

    }

    this.$forceUpdate();
  }
```

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you're attempting with the `$forceUpdate`, but I'm not certain that's [the intended behavior here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate). In particular, by directly modifying the property of an Object in an Array, I believe Vue is missing the changes completely, so it doesn't know what to forceUpdate.

(See these links to read more on when Vue does / doesn't recognize mutations to [Objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) and [Arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays))

TBH I've never attempted to use forceUpdate in this way, but I **have** done some Array mutation in a spreadsheet-like scenario before and it was a pain... I would avoid it if at all possible.

Rather than modifying a property in the array, I'd compute the filter on-the-fly using a method. You should get the reactivity you want because you're calculating, not mutating, the properties of the list of projects.

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['myprojects'],

  data() {
    return {
      searchinput: ''
    }
  },

  computed: {
    activeProjects() {
      return this.myprojects.filter(this.isInSearch)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    isInSearch(project) {
      return project.name.includes(this.searchinput)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: With a bit of restructuring of my code, this worked really well. I added another variable  so it wouldnt automatically update as soon as I typed in anything in the searchbar but only when I click on search

Answer (score 1):

Vue caches nodes based on `:key` value. You're passing the entire object, you should be using a unique property on your `project`.

Try yo use `name` or an unique id if you have one.

````
<ion-list>
        <div v-for="project in activeProjects" :key="project.name">
          <ion-item v-if="checkemail!=project.creator">
            <ion-button @click="openProjectPage(project.id)">{{ project.name }}</ion-button>
          </ion-item>
      </div>
</ion-list>```
````

Comment: It did work without a unique key before I added the code to actively change the computed property. I changed the key now, but it still does not rerender.